# MATLAB: pdist, finding pixel locations of minimum pairwise distance in binary image

Tags: matlab, binary, distance

I have a binary image and have found the minimum distance connecting two nearby regions of interest/connected components using

```
min(min(pdist2(CCstats(1).PixelList,CCstats(2).PixelList)))
```

I also need to get the coordinates of these ends of this distance/the most adjacent pixels between these 2 regions of interest

I plan on drawing a line along this distance. I was going to use something like:

```
x=linspace(coord1(1), coord2(1),1000);
y=linspace(coord1(2), coord2(2),1000);
index=sub2ind(size(image),round(y),round(x));
image(index)=1;
```

Any suggestions for how to find these coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

You will want the second output of `min` (combined with `ind2sub`) to determine the row/column of the `pdist2` matrix that corresponds to the minimum distance.

```
distances = pdist2(CCstats(1).PixelList, CCstats(2).PixelList);
[mindist, minind] = min(distances(:));

%// Now convert this linear index into index1/index2 into your pixel lists
[index1, index2] = ind2sub(size(distances), minind);

%// Now grab the coordinates using these index values
coord1 = CCstats(1).PixelList(index1,:);
coord2 = CCstats(2).PixelList(index2,:);
```